# POST request to JIRA REST API on a remote machine

Tags: r, post, curl, jira-rest-api

How do I talk to the REST API of a JIRA installation that runs on a remote server?

### Details

I'd like to work through [this little example](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis) of how to interact with JIRA's REST API.

This is the request I'd like to issue:

```
curl -u admin:admin -X POST --data @data.txt -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:2990/jira/rest/api/2/issue/
```

My JIRA application runs on an AWS machine with, say, the following URL:

`http://aws-url:8080`

This is the R call I used for sending the POST request:

```
httr::POST("http://aws-url:8080/jira/rest/api/2/issue/", 
  "-u" = "myuser:mypassword", 
  "--data" = "@data.json", 
  "-H" = "Content-Type: application/json")
```

However, I get the following `404` response:

```
Response [http://aws-url:8080/jira/rest/api/2/issue/]
  Date: 2016-07-15 14:28
  Status: 404
  Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
  Size: 2.76 kB
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head><meta charset="utf-8"><meta http-equiv="X-UA-C...


<ul class="atlassian-footer">
    <li>
        Atlassian JIRA <a class="seo-link" rel="nofollow" href="https://www.atlassi...



        <span id="footer-build-information">(v7.1.9#71013-<span title='1aa0586d78ef...
...
```

So I'm guessing I either misspecified the URL (or am still misunderstanding how the REST API of my JIRA instance needs to be contacted) and/or misspecified the call to `POST`?

Sorry, not really familiar with the whole web technology stack yet. The question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394956/synchronizing-issues-between-jira-and-github)

### Update

Tried this request instead, but got the same result:

```
httr::POST(url,
  body = "-u myuser:mypassword --data @data.json",
  encode = "json"
)
```

Comment: Sadly there's no clue about the reason for the 404, I think the call to httr::POST if wrong anyway, it doesn't take parameters as curl does, you will have to read your file as text value to pass it as `body` variable, probably using `encode="json"` too. see `?httr:POST` for details.

Comment: Cool, thanks. That's a start :-)

Answer (score 1):

404 means "not found", so there's simply something wrong with url you use.

What do you get if you paste something like this in a browser?

```
http://aws-url:8080/jira/rest/api/2/issue/{anExistingIssueKey}
```

Also if you access JIRA through the browser, do you use http://aws-url:8080/jira or does it have something else than /jira?

Comment: Thanks man. I was able to shed some light onto this (see my answer)

Answer (score 1):

### URL structure

Seems like the actual URL needs to be like this:

```
http://aws-url:8080/rest/api/2/issue/
```

or

```
http://aws-url:8080/rest/api/latest/issue/
```

instead of

```
http://aws-url:8080/jira/rest/api/latest/issue/
```

assuming that your JIRA instance runs on port `8080`

I'm not quite sure why it's okay to drop the `context` (which would be `jira` in my case) from the URL as this [resource](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/7.0-SNAPSHOT/) suggests the URL structure needs to be like this:

```
http://host:port/context/rest/api-name/api-version/resource-name
```

The only explanation I have for that as a web-dev n00b is that I'm already explicitly adressing the JIRA instance by it's port number somehow? I might however be mixing up the meaning of `context` and `api-name` as well (not that deep into that stuff yet ;-)). Could it be that `api-name` gets a default value if omitted?

### `GET` request

This GET request

```
res <- GET(http://aws-url:8080/rest/api/latest/issue/{anExistingIssueKey},
    authenticate("user", "password"))
```

gives me a `200` response with all the issue details of an issue that already existed.

### `POST` request

The actual `POST` request needs to look like this:

```
url <- "http://aws-url:8080/rest/api/latest/issue/"
res <- POST(url,
  authenticate("user", "password"),
  body = upload_file("data.txt"),
  encode = "json"
)
```

and gives you a `201` response